# How to determine the current active view in tabbarcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with three tabs. In one of the viewcontrollers belong to the middle tab, my code needed to determine if the active view is the first viewcontroller's view.  Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell which view controller is the active one by calling the [`selectedViewController` property of your app's UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController)(documentation linked for you).

There's also a `selectedIndex` property as well.